# Accessing Secrets Manager passwords from Postgress Foreign Data Wrappers. (FDW)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, secretsmanager

I have Foreign Data wrappers in Postgress SQL connecting to Oracle databases, whose passwords are stored in Secrets Manager.

Can I access Secrets Manager passwords from Postgress SQL, I mean reference those passwords stored in Secrets manager and use that passwords in PostgreSQL scripts?

How do I access secrets Manager passwords in SQL queries?

I'm still looking for a solution

Comment: Usually this is handled in the user mapping, within the PostgreSQL database. Unless your (unknown) foreign data wrapper supports something different. See also the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createusermapping.html